# Markov Chain Fundamental Matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling, markov-process, maple

I am modeling baseball using a Markov chain model. I am  using matrix theory to calculate the number of times in each state using N=(I-Q)^-1. However in Maple, when I take the inverse of (I-Q) it results is a matrix with mostly negative values. Any idea why this could be happening? Let me know if you want more info/the code I'm using.

Comment: Giving an example of the transition matrix would help, for starters...

Comment: What is $Q$? Is $I$ the identity matrix? With the information currently given, my idea of why you get negative values in the matrix is because you have entered something wrong.